# Javascript object search

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this code: (it reads a folder of mp3 files and retrieves all paths)

```
var base = "../media/audio/";

var arr1 = [
    {path:"../media/audio/Numbers/Cat1/01.mp3"},
    {path:"../media/audio/Numbers/Cat1/02.mp3"},
    {path:"../media/audio/Numbers/Cat1/03.mp3"},
    {path:"../media/audio/Numbers/Cat1/04.mp3"},

    {path:"../media/audio/Letters/Cat1/01.mp3"},
    {path:"../media/audio/Letters/Cat1/02.mp3"},
    {path:"../media/audio/Letters/Cat1/03.mp3"},

    {path:"../media/audio/Color/Cat1/01.mp3"},
    {path:"../media/audio/Color/Cat1/02.mp3"},
    {path:"../media/audio/Color/Cat1/03.mp3"}
];
```

I want to get this:

```
var arr2 = [
[{
    category:"Numbers", 
    path:[
        {path:"../media/audio/Numbers/Cat1/01.mp3"},
        {path:"../media/audio/Numbers/Cat1/02.mp3"},
        {path:"../media/audio/Numbers/Cat1/03.mp3"},
        {path:"../media/audio/Numbers/Cat1/04.mp3"}
    ]
}],
[{
    category:"Letters", 
    path:[
        {path:"../media/audio/Letters/Cat1/01.mp3"},
        {path:"../media/audio/Letters/Cat1/02.mp3"},
        {path:"../media/audio/Letters/Cat1/03.mp3"}
    ]
}],
[{
    category:"Color", 
    path:[
        {path:"../media/audio/Color/Cat1/01.mp3"},
        {path:"../media/audio/Color/Cat1/02.mp3"},
        {path:"../media/audio/Color/Cat1/03.mp3"}
    ]
}]
];
```

Find every category after the 'base' string, split them in array, inside each array and object with category and path property.

Comment: Okay. What have you tried?

Comment: javascript can not read your folder. You should have server side script for this, if so - include it in your question.

Comment: The question isn't about whether or not he can access the files listed, he just wants to group the contents of the array using JS.

That said, the asker should provide some code to show what he has tried. SO shouldn't be treated as a "insert problem, receive code" machine. You should try to solve it yourself first and come to SO for help with your solution.

Comment: Thought it's about to have already clean (grouped) output from a server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

```js
var output = document.getElementById("output");

function splitSearch(base, arr1) {
  var categoryList = {};
  var baseLen = base.length;

  // Split paths into categories
  arr1.forEach(function(inPath) {
      var subPath = inPath.path.substr(baseLen);
      var category = subPath.split("/")[0];
      if (!categoryList.hasOwnProperty(category)) {
        categoryList[category] = [];
      }
      categoryList[category].push(inPath);
    });
  
  // Transform categoryList into array format requested
  var arr2 = [];
  for (var category in categoryList) {
    arr2.push({ category: category, path: categoryList[category] });
  }
  
  return arr2;
}

var base = "../media/audio/";

var arr1 = [
    {path:"../media/audio/Numbers/Cat1/01.mp3"},
    {path:"../media/audio/Numbers/Cat1/02.mp3"},
    {path:"../media/audio/Numbers/Cat1/03.mp3"},
    {path:"../media/audio/Numbers/Cat1/04.mp3"},

    {path:"../media/audio/Letters/Cat1/01.mp3"},
    {path:"../media/audio/Letters/Cat1/02.mp3"},
    {path:"../media/audio/Letters/Cat1/03.mp3"},

    {path:"../media/audio/Color/Cat1/01.mp3"},
    {path:"../media/audio/Color/Cat1/02.mp3"},
    {path:"../media/audio/Color/Cat1/03.mp3"}
];

var result = splitSearch(base, arr1);

output.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(result);
```

```html
<div id="output" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

```
var arr1 = [
    {path:"../media/audio/Numbers/Cat1/01.mp3"},
    {path:"../media/audio/Numbers/Cat1/02.mp3"},
    {path:"../media/audio/Numbers/Cat1/03.mp3"},
    {path:"../media/audio/Numbers/Cat1/04.mp3"},

    {path:"../media/audio/Letters/Cat1/01.mp3"},
    {path:"../media/audio/Letters/Cat1/02.mp3"},
    {path:"../media/audio/Letters/Cat1/03.mp3"},

    {path:"../media/audio/Color/Cat1/01.mp3"},
    {path:"../media/audio/Color/Cat1/02.mp3"},
    {path:"../media/audio/Color/Cat1/03.mp3"}
];

var basePath = "\.\.\/media\/audio\/";
var regex = new RegExp('^' + basePath + '(.*?)\/');

var categories = {}, arr2 = [];

for (var i=0, x=arr1.length; i < x; i++) {
    var category = arr1[i].path.match(regex)[1];

    if (!categories[category]) {        
        arr2.push({ 
           category : category,
           path : []
        });
        categories[category] = true;
    }

    for (var ii=0, l = arr2.length; ii < l; ii++) {
        if (arr2[ii].category == category) {
           arr2[ii].path.push(arr1[i]);
           break;
        }
    }
}
```

Could probably be cleaned up a bit but should get you where you need to go